# How to connect a mobile and a printer via WIFI to print a text file in android?

Tags: android, wifi

Can anyone tell me how to connect a mobile and a printer via Wifi to print a text file in android?That is,if i press the print button from the android application,the printer has to print that corresponding file.As per my knowledge i have searched for it in Google, but i couldn't find any good samples to do it.Has anyone have at-least one sample android program to do this, it will be better to clear my chaos.

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ther is no api provided by google (<19, thanks to @KaranJ), so third part solutions have to be done, eg:

http://www.printershare.com/help-android-integration.sdf
https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android

a standalone solution would be very difficult! :/

you could use an alert dialog builder, to guide the user to the google playstore, for installing something like printshare or google cloud print.

EDIT

also the content should be laid out to be ready for printing, more here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintManager.html
http://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html

Answer (score 0):

Wireless printing api are only available in api level 19, so I think you should go with the answer of @thenobol